# using combo box draw item event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using ComboBox DrawItem event, but when I use this the selected item is not working.

I mean that I press right click on a specific item in the combo box but randomly some other item is shown on the selected line in the ComboBox (although the actual item that selected is just fine, it just shows that some other item was selected)

This is my code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox;
comboBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
comboBox.AllowDrop = true;
comboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
comboBox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;

comboBox.DrawItem += (sender, DrawItemEventArgs) =>
{
   Font font = comboBox.Font;
   Brush backgroundColor;
   Brush textColor;
   if (indexes.Contains(DrawItemEventArgs.Index))
   {
      if ((DrawItemEventArgs.State & DrawItemState.Selected)==DrawItemState.Selected)
      {
         backgroundColor = Brushes.Cyan;
         textColor = Brushes.Black;
      }
      else
      {
         backgroundColor = Brushes.Brown;
         textColor = Brushes.Black;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if ((DrawItemEventArgs.State & DrawItemState.Selected)==DrawItemState.Selected)
      {
         backgroundColor = SystemBrushes.Highlight;
         textColor = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
      }
      else
      {
         backgroundColor = SystemBrushes.Window;
         textColor = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
      }
   }
   DrawItemEventArgs.Graphics.FillRectangle(backgroundColor, DrawItemEventArgs.Bounds);
   if (DrawItemEventArgs.Index == -1)     return;

   DrawItemEventArgs.Graphics.DrawString((sender as ComboBox).
   Items[DrawItemEventArgs.Index].ToString(), font,textColor,DrawItemEventArgs.Bounds);
};
```

Is something wrong with my paint? Because I debugged and find that this event is making the trouble.

tnx.

Comment: sorry, indexes contains the specific indexes that i want to colorize in the combo box @Ganesh_Devlekar

Comment: I don't think you are passing the variables to the lambda expression correctly. Shouldn't it be something like: `comboBox.DrawItem += (sender, e)` and inside the body use 'e' where you used DrawItemEventArgs ?

Comment: Your code works just fine. The right items get painted and I can't see that a wrong one gets selected. Is there code in the selection event? where did you put the code you have shown us?

Comment: @o_weisman I can't undoo the upvote anymore, but the lambda expression is just fine, provided sender is not a duplicate. I would however indeed call the param e to keep in line with the normal naming scheme.

Comment: it failed for this error : e does not contain a definition for 'selected'.

Comment: You don't reference `Selected` in `e` resp. in `DrawItemEventArgs` but in the `DrawItemState` enumeration of which it is a member. So you may want to replace `DrawItemEventArgs` with `e` but it will not make a difference for the working of the code. Again, your code works fine; if you have problems they come from another part of your program.

Comment: The question makes little sense.  You cannot select an item from the dropdown with a right-click.  What you paint with DrawItem never has anything to do with what gets selected.  I'd guess you'd better chase down what on Earth a right-click is doing in your app.

Comment: i meant left click of course.. excuse me..

Comment: I agree with Hans, DrawItem is called to draw the dropped down items, but it sounds like the problem you are having is that the wrong item is being selected into the edit box after you select one of the items from the drop down list. Is that your issue?